# Heroku migration from Cedar to Bamboo, how to convert PST stored dates into UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have an application running on Heroku Bamboo and I need to migrate it to Cedar, but I have a problem with dates, because of my `default_timezone`:

```
# config/application.rb
config.time_zone = "Brasilia"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

With this configuration AR saves the date fields using PST (which is the `:local` value for Bamboo).

But it doesn't save the TZ info in the date fields, it only offsets the dates to PST, for example the values on PG are like `2015-01-26 17:20:00` with no TZ info.

After the Cedar migration and because of `:local`, AR assumes that `2015-01-26 17:20:00` is in UTC, causing wrong date values.

If I set `heroku config:set TZ=America/Los_Angeles` and use `my_date_field.in_time_zone` for all my date fields in the interface, it works on Cedar, but I doesn't feel that right.

Any ideas on other ways to fix that?

### Problem solved

After setting `ruby 1.9.2` on Cedar (default is 2.0) and with TZ set to  America/Los_Angeles it worked in the same way it was working on Bamboo without requiring `.in_time_zone`.

Although I still don't know why 2.0 requires `.in_time_zone` to return the time using the TZ configured with `config.time_zone`.